# I want the original Game Center achievement icon, but how?

Tags: iphone, xcode, app-store-connect

iTunes Connect requires me to upload an icon for every achievement. But I see nothing wrong with the original icon ... still I need to supply my own.

Does anybody have a snapshot of the original I can overlay over the original?

Or how would I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you obtained the icon and over-layed it, your app would be rejected. You are not allowed to use any of Apples graphics.

Comment: Probably that's why google is empty of it :-/ ... I will use something from the in-game style.